# Java Settings Menu

Tags: java, windows

I am curently working on a GUI and when clicking a certain button:

```
settingsB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Settings");
            
        }
    });
```

Instead of just printing it there should a new window open where you can adjust settings with sliders textboxes, ... How would you approach that? With new classes or all inside the action listener?

Edit:
My "current solution" is based on the great suggestion from user Holger to call a method showSettingsDialogue():

```
private void showSettingsDialogue() {
        if(settingsOpen) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            settingsOpen = true;
            settingWindow = new SettingsWindow();
            settingWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    settingsOpen = false;
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
            });
        }
```

Unfortunally with this way I have to write down even unimplemented methods. Any bether solution then this?

Comment: Surely not everything within an action listener. This, however doesn’t imply that you need more classes. Just calling a method of the surrounding class would be enough. For example, create a method `showSettingsDialog` in the surrounding class and use a delegating listener like `settingsB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { showSettingsDialog(); } });` or even simpler `settingsB.addActionListener(e -> showSettingsDialog());`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it to work that with a click on settings button a jframe opens and a boolean "isSettingsOpen" makes sure that only one setting menu can be opened at a time. But how do I check for the window to be closde again?

Comment: My current solution is like this:

Comment: private void showSettingsDialogue() {
  if(settingsOpen) {
   return;
  }
  else {
   settingsOpen = true;
   settingWindow = new SettingsWindow();
   settingWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    
   @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
     settingsOpen = false;
     
    } I have to implement all the other methods too. Is there a more  efficient way?

Comment: You can extend [`WindowAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) instead of implementing `WindowListener`. `settingWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { settingsOpen = false; } });`

Comment: You probably should use a `JDialog` for the settings.

Comment: Don't use extra booleans to track state.  Just disable the button when the dialog opens and re-enable when it closes.